# Maxent: number of presence records for training and testing

Tags: geospatial, maxent

I run Maxent using 20 presence data and set the 'Random test percentage' as 25 %.

The HTML output shows me '7 presence records used for training, 2 for testing'.

I don't understand why the total amount of input and output data are different.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? I think 7 training data is too small to run models.

Many thanks,